# Output device changed but not getting sound output

Tags: macos, audio

I am using macOS Mojave v10.14.5. After I plugged in my headphones (while the MacBook is not plugged into power and opening KMPlayer to listen music on speakers), I was unable to get the sound output my headphone. Still the actual sound came out from MacBook Pro speakers instead of headphones.
Any idea on this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure KMPlayer is not overriding the default speaker setup? Have you tried going to Main Controls > Audio > Audio Renderer and setting your device as default?

Comment: Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concse](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).   - From Review